# Why $\|x\| \leq \liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, limsup-and-liminf

If $\|x\|$ converges weakly to $x$, then $\|x\| \leq \liminf_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \|x_n\|$.

Can someone explain this? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A proof? Or the intuition why it is plausible that it is true? What do you already know?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470217/norm-is-weakly-lower-semicontinuous)

Comment: I don't understand the proof in the related post. I can see $\|x\| = \lim \inf \|x_n\|$. But where is the "$<$" from?

Comment: @baNv  Are you talking about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/631122/70305)? If so, note that $|\phi(x_n)|\leq\|\phi\|_{\text{op}}\|x_n\|=\|x_n\|$

Comment: I'm lost at this step: $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} |\phi (x_n) |
\leq \liminf _{n \rightarrow \infty} |\phi (x_n) |$, why $\leq$? I thought it should be $\geq$.